# JSON.stringify of an object returns just {}

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to turn a javascript object into a JSON. The object is correctly formed, and `console.log(myObject)` returns it correctly.

However, `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));` returns just `{}`

What am I missing here?
Edit: the object in question:

```
 Object
  autor: "Administrador"
  descripcion: "At Google I/O 2015, everything we’ve seen and learned about is under the command of Sundar Pichai. In this exclusive interview, he walks us through his product vision.↵↵Subscribe: http://goo.gl/G5RXGs↵↵Check out our full video catalog: http://goo.gl/lfcGfq↵Visit our playlists: http://goo.gl/94XbKx↵Like The Verge on Facebook: http://goo.gl/2P1aGc↵Follow on Twitter: http://goo.gl/XTWX61↵Follow on Instagram: http://goo.gl/7ZeLvX↵Read More: http://www.theverge.com"
  titulo: "The future of Google with Sundar Pichai"
  url_imagen: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TguamcqrQjI/sddefault.jpg"
  url_video: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TguamcqrQjI"
  __proto__: Object
```

edit: Here's how I create the object:

```
var myObject = {};
    $http.get('apiCallToYoutubeIcantShareHereCauseItContainsAPrivateKey')
    .success(function(data) {

      myObject.titulo = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['title'];
      myObject.descripcion = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['description'];
      myObject.url_video ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idYoutube;
      myObject.url_imagen = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['thumbnails']['standard']["url"];
      myObject.autor = 'Administrador';
    });
```

Comment: what does `myObject` look like?

Comment: @AmmarCSE like this: http://imgur.com/zsGFl76

Comment: @kace91 Don't add image add it as text

Comment: @kace91 Not this from the `console` but the actual one

Comment: Don't add the console output, add the actualy object from the code! Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/zu2L3h5x/ , the whole `var object = { ... }`

Comment: var myObject = {
    "autor": "Administrador",
    "descripcion": "At Google I/O 2015, everything we’ve seen and learned about is under the command of Sundar Pichai.In this exclusive interview, he walks us through his product vision.Subscribe: http://goo.gl/G5RXGsFollow on Twitter: http://goo.gl/XTWX61↵Follow on Instagram: http://goo.gl/7ZeLvX ",
    "titulo": "The future of Google with Sundar Pichai",
    "url_imagen": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TguamcqrQjI/sddefault.jpg",
    "url_video": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TguamcqrQjI"
};

alert(JSON.stringify(myObject));

Comment: Add ` s around it or edit the question and add 4 spaces inbefore

Comment: @CagatayUlubay I've added how I create the object too.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay Also, your sample object does work, so I guess there's something wrong with this object in particular.

Comment: Do you `console.log` inside the `succes(function(data){ .. })`? And when you do, `myObject` is filled, but the stringyfied version is empty? Can you also do `console.log( typeof myObject );` ?

Comment: Do you ever discover the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, you are trying to print the object before receiving it from server (`It's an asynchronous request`). Try to print it at the end of the `success` message, or use Promise/Deferred concepts

```
var myObject = {};
    $http.get('apiCallToYoutubeIcantShareHereCauseItContainsAPrivateKey')
    .success(function(data) {

      myObject.titulo = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['title'];
      myObject.descripcion = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['description'];
      myObject.url_video ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idYoutube;
      myObject.url_imagen = data['items'][0]["snippet"]['thumbnails']['standard']["url"];
      myObject.autor = 'Administrador';

      console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `myObject` is still in scope at the point you execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));`

If you execute the following statement in the console you will see it works fine:

`var web = { "domain":"mammothworkwear.com","keywords":["Helly Hansen", "Snickers"]}; console.log(JSON.stringify(web));`

I'm guessing your `myObject` is empty

Edit:

The JSON you posted above does not validate, paste it into http://jsonlint.com/

If you fix the formatting issues and run it all in the console, it works as expected:

```
var myObject = {
    autor: "Administrador",
    descripcion: "At Google I/O 2015, everything we’ve seen and learned about is under the command of Sundar Pichai. In this exclusive interview, he walks us through his product vision.↵↵Subscribe: http://goo.gl/G5RXGs↵↵Check out our full video catalog: http://goo.gl/lfcGfq↵Visit our playlists: http://goo.gl/94XbKx↵Like The Verge on Facebook: http://goo.gl/2P1aGc↵Follow on Twitter: http://goo.gl/XTWX61↵Follow on Instagram: http://goo.gl/7ZeLvX↵Read More: http://www.theverge.com",
    titulo: "The future of Google with Sundar Pichai",
    url_imagen: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TguamcqrQjI/sddefault.jpg",
    url_video: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TguamcqrQjI"
}; 
console.log(myObject); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Comment: myObject can´t be empty because I´m making the console.log() calls to both the object and the stringified version at the same time, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have 2 semicolons `;` inside your object that doesn't belong there.

Your current code:

```
var myObject = {
    "autor": "Administrador",
    "descripcion": "At Google I/O 2015, everything we’ve seen and learned about is under the command of Sundar Pichai.In this exclusive interview, he walks us through his product vision.Subscribe: goo.gl/G5RXGsFollow on Twitter: goo.gl/XTWX61↵Follow on Instagram: goo.gl/7ZeLvX ",
    "titulo": "The future of Google with Sundar Pichai",
    "url_imagen": "i.ytimg.com/vi/TguamcqrQjI/sddefault.jpg";, // <-- Semicolon that doesn't belong here
    "url_video": "youtube.com/embed/TguamcqrQjI"; // <-- Semicolon that doesn't belong here
};
```

Following the Object without them:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zu2L3h5x/1/

```
var myObject = { 
    "autor": "Administrador",
    "descripcion": "At Google I/O 2015, everything we’ve seen and learned about is under the command of Sundar Pichai.In this exclusive interview, he walks us through his product vision.Subscribe: goo.gl/G5RXGsFollow on Twitter: goo.gl/XTWX61↵Follow on Instagram: goo.gl/7ZeLvX ",
    "titulo": "The future of Google with Sundar Pichai",
    "url_imagen": "i.ytimg.com/vi/TguamcqrQjI/sddefault.jpg",
    "url_video": "youtube.com/embed/TguamcqrQjI"
};
```

Comment: That is not my code. Someone else added it in the comments, I think you thought it was me who posted that.

Comment: Oh, well.. I will look at your edit and edit my answer. I really thought it was you.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you JSON.stringify call produces an error which is caught somehow and that's why the result is an empty object. But it's hard to say without the real code and/or the context in which you use it.